# preg_match escape character returns void array

Tags: php, preg-match

i have to find this chars sequence `"<div"`
I use this pattern: `"/\<div/"` but the result array for preg_match is null: 
Array ( [0] =>

```
$domObject = "iajsdijasidijsad<div class=\"_3-ma _2bne\">`</div>sidjiasdjiasjdiasjid";`
$pattern = '/\<div/';
preg_match($pattern, $domObject, $result);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la)

Comment: and you don't need any escape caracter here : http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=93744

Comment: '/<div/' : returns void array.. Array ( [0] =>

Comment: That's not even valid PHP code. Can you please edit the question and clean up the code? Whatever, your haystack does not seem to have any `\<` string. Do you mean `</` by chance?